# Generating hashcode without using Double.GetHashCode()

Tags: c#, hashcode

I need to generate hashcode out of following struct:

```
    public struct Vector2
    {
        private double x;
        private double y;

        public Vector2(double x, double y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public override Int32 GetHashCode()
        {
            return ????;
        }
    }
```

Now the issue is, I cannot use:

```
double.GetHashCode() or int.GetHashCode()

x.GetHashCode() ^ (y.GetHashCode() << 2);
```

because we convert C# code into JavaScript using Bridge.Net and this code decreases performance drastically.

Comment: It doesn’t really matter whether this decreases performance. You **must** use it for correctness, unless there is some extraneous knowledge that constrains the range of values your structure will take.

Comment: what version of .net are you targetting - theres now `System.HashCode` that can simplify this.

Comment: `int.GetHashCode()` justs returns the same value as the `int` itself.

Comment: The GetHash is a first part of a comparison and does not get a unique value.  To make quick you can just use ((int)x).GetHashCode() ^ (((int(y).GetHashCode() << 2);  The speed probably has something to do with the processing of a math double.  I suspect your compile options are debug and if you change to release it probably will run a lot quicker.

Comment: @jdweng While you *could* do this, it’s on the face of it a pretty bad idea, because it computes a poor hash, and would thus make performance substantially worse. This is assuming that we have no information about the expected distribution of input values. But your suggested hash is assuming some *very* specific properties of the input distribution.

Comment: @Wrymn Actually why are you implementing your own `GetHashCode`? After all, you’re not implementing your own `Equals` and using the default. Since your type is a `struct`, the default `GetHashCode` should work just fine.

Comment: We do not know the distribution so saying this is a bad idea is just guessing.  The original code show not be affecting performance so there is something the processing of doubles or the number of items in the hash is huge and causing a memory issue.  Really the solution is to find out what is causing the performance issue.

Comment: @jdweng It *is* a bad idea *in the absence of specific information* to the contrary. Your solution makes extremely specific, unrealistic assumptions about the input distribution, without stating those assumptions clearly.

Answer (score 0):

For structs, you don't need equality or hashcode implementations. You still need == and != operator overloads, but that is all.

If you want to use class instead of structs for things like Vector2, you have no choice but to implement equality and hashcode methods.